# Regex match multiple numbers stop at string (word) despite more matches exist

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

**Goal;**
Match all variations of phone numbers with 8 digits + (optional) country code.
Stop match when "keyword" is found, even if more matches exist after the "keyword".
Need this in a one-liner and have tried a plethora of variations with lookahead/behind and negate [^keyword] but I am unable to understand how to achieve this.

**Example of text;**

abra 90998855
kadabra 04 94 84 54
cat 132 23 564
oh the nice Hat +41985 32 565
+17 98 56 32 56

Ladida

keyword

*I Want It To Stop Matching Here Or Right Before The "keyword"*

more nice text with some matches
cat 132 23 564
oh the nice Hat +41985 32 565
+17 98 56 32 56

**Example of regex;**

```
(\+\d{1,2})?[\s]?\(?\d{2,3}\)?[\s]?(\d{2})[\s]?(\d{2})?[\s]?(\d{2,3})
```

-> This matches all numbers also below the keyword

```
(\+\d{1,2})?[\s]?\(?\d{2,3}\)?[\s]?(\d{2})[\s]?(\d{2})?[\s]?(\d{2,3})[^keyword]
```

-> This matches all numbers also below the keyword

```
(\+\d{1,2})?[\s]?\(?\d{2,3}\)?[\s]?(\d{2})[\s]?(\d{2})?[\s]?(\d{2,3})(?!keyword)
```

-> This matches all numbers also below the keyword

```
(\+\d{1,2})?[\s]?\(?\d{2,3}\)?[\s]?(\d{2})[\s]?(\d{2})?[\s]?(\d{2,3})(?=keyword)
```

-> This matches nothing

```
((\+\d{1,2})?[\s]?\(?\d{2,3}\)?[\s]?(\d{2})[\s]?(\d{2})?[\s]?(\d{2,3})(?:(?!keyword))*)
```

-> This matches all numbers also below the keyword

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/M6oqlH/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if there are multiple occurences of the keyword it will match numbers after the first occurence, which I don't think is what OP wants

Comment: @Aaron See https://regex101.com/r/M6oqlH/2